# Extension Method to Add Items to Enum

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am trying to write an extension method that will add additional items to an enum.

I have never written an extension method and have looked at and tried several examples that I found here on Stackoverflow and on other internet sites, but none seem to address exactly what I am trying to do.  I am trying to extend the Windows.Form.DialogResult Class.  I have tried the code below:

```
public static class SaveTestDialog
{
    public enum CustomDialog( this DialogResult dialogResult )
    {
        return ApiKey = 8;
        return Default = 9;
    }

}
```

I thought perhaps the problem was that it was because it was a Windows  method so I tried just a simple enum in the project and got the same results:

```
public static class CustomSchedule 
{
    public enum NewSchedule( Schedule schedule )
    {
        return Weekly = 3;
        return Contract = 4;
    }

}
```

For the DialogResult, I expect to be able to get DialogResult.ApiKey and DialogResult.Default options when using the CustomDialog in my application.  I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Enums are a compile time constant, why are you trying to add more during runtime?

Comment: Just a suggestion - you're trying two new things at once - trying to write an extension method, and trying to add to an `enum` (which, as pointed out, you can't do.) This may lead to some confusion where you're wondering which of those two is the problem. I'd try a) writing a simple extension method for something that you know works, and b) trying to do the other thing without an extension (although that's a moot point now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods add new instance-like methods to a type. They do not allow you to add actual members to a type. What you're trying to do is not possible.

There's no reason you couldn't do `(DialogResult)8` and make that a constant.

```
public static class ExtraDialogResults
{
    public const DialogResult ApiKey = (DialogResult)8;
    // and so on...
}
```

**But**... just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*.  A better way would be to define your own enum that has the results you need and wrap the dialog functionality in something that returns that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I will try this in lieu of a better solution.  I'm not sure what you mean by "wrap the dialog functionality in something that returns that", but I would love to learn.  If you should happen to stumble across some code that shows an example of what you are talking about, I would truly appreciate a link.

Comment: I just mean writing your own dialog (WinForms, WPF, whichever you're using) that returns a member of your own enum type. When the user clicks any of the buttons you have on the dialog, return your custom result enum value to indicate the user's choice.

Comment: Oh, it just wouldn't be tied to DialogResult.  I get it.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use this.  Although it shows in my list of "choices"  my button does not pass it as a value, so I still can't use it.

Comment: This question turned out to be an X/Y problem. I would suggest asking a new question with information about what you're trying to accomplish (vs. how you intend to accomplish something). Make sure you tag `[winforms]` or `[wpf]` so you get the right audience.

Comment: I attached to button and it gave the error:System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException: 'The value of argument 'value' (8) is invalid for Enum type 'DialogResult'.
Parameter name: value'.  I thank you for trying to help.  I will have to figure out how to get the value of these buttons some other way.  Thanks again.